# InvalidCastException 'HttpResponseMessage' to 'IHttpActionResult' on WebApi2 GET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

Recently I've been following some WebApi2 tutorials.  I have a situation whereby if a requested GET operation returns data outside of the user's remit, then I need to return a Forbidden code.

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web.Http

Namespace Controllers

    Public Class MyController
        Inherits ApiController

        <Route("Records/{id}")>
        Public Function [Get](id As Int32) As IHttpActionResult
            If Not Remit.IsWithinRemit(id) Then
                Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "This data is not within your remit")
            Else
                Dim r As New CustomObject(id)
                Return Ok(r)
            End If
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Unfortunately, although the `Ok(r)` part works okay, `CreateErrorResponse` throws an `InvalidCastException`:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult'.

I know why the error is happening, but am unsure of the correct approach of how to fix it.
In other threads, people advise that `CreateErrorResponse()` is the best approach for WebApi2, but VS creates it's sample GET request returning `IHttpActionResult`.  Its like stuff doesn't seem to fit together for us newbies at the moment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

Change your `Get` method to return `"HttpResponseMessage"`

```
<Route("Records/{id}")>
Public Function [Get](id As Int32) As HttpResponseMessage
    If Not Remit.IsWithinRemit(id) Then
        Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "This data is not within your remit")
    Else
        Dim r As New CustomObject(id)
        Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, r)
    End If
End Function
```

Check below link

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/action-results

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't obvious, but you can get what you want (error code plus message) AND return it from a method of type `IHttpActionResult`. No need to change the return type or go without error messages.

This is the helper class:

```cs
public class ErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private HttpRequestMessage Request { get; }
        private HttpStatusCode statusCode;
        private string message;

        public ErrorResult(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        {
            this.Request = request;
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message));
        }
    }
```

and you can call it like this:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult MyMethod()
{
    MyServiceLayer myServiceLayer = new MyServiceLayer();
    MyType myvar;
    if (MyServiceLayer.EverythingIsOK(ref myvar))
        return Ok(myvar);
    else 
        return new ErrorResult(Request, HttpStatusCode.SomeErrorCode, "Something Is Wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative *possible* solution (there may be better but this one works and is simple).  It returns

> 403 Forbidden

but with no content:

```
<Route("Records/{id}")>
Public Function [Get](id As Int32) As IHttpActionResult
    If Not Remit.IsWithinRemit(id) Then
        Return New Results.StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, Request)
    Else
        Dim r As New CustomObject(id)
        Return Ok(r)
    End If
End Function
```

Because `HttpResponseMessage` comes from the [same namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), and also allows you to return custom error messages in addition to a [HTTP status code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that option is more suitable to use in most cases.

I guess `IHttpActionResult` is for basic status code returns with no frills.  I posted this alongside the above answer to give new coders visibility of both options.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error using .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Rather than changing the return type** from `IHttpActionResult`, I corrected the bug by wrapping my`HttpResponseMessage` object in a `ResponseMessageResult` like this: -

`return new ResponseMessageResult(myHttpResponseMessage);`

** it was a single, custom `case` amongst a set of straightforward `IHttpActionResult` cases in a `switch` block